# How to hide public DNS

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've an instance of ubuntu on amazon; it also gives a public DNS for me like ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com which is opened to world.

I've my own DNS which I link with amazon hosting/instance and I would like to hide public DNS from amazon to avoid duplicate of content for google SEO.

Is it possible and if so how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you just CNAME so the search bot's identify them as duplicates or is your site more complex requiring multiple unique hosts provided similar content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is configure your web server to respond just to the domain name. Technically speaking, you could access the web server on the ip address if you do not use virtual hosts.

Comment: as far as I can do that, its a solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

- set up your hostname accordingly
- adjust your reverse-DNS entry
- delete the A-entry for the amazon-hostname (be sure to have your server-IP at hand in case you mistyped something!)
- double-check every service for configuration-mistakes, make the services bind themselves explicitly on your own domain

Comment: Reverse DNS has to be handled on Amazon's side of things.  You can fill out [this form](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) to request the change, but it has to be for an Elastic IP, not a specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up both domains as your's in the Google Webmaster Tools and then set your "real" DNS name to be the preferred one.  You are not hiding it you are just telling google that they are the same site.